# Using vba to import multiple csv's into a single sheet, and then copy and paste a filtered version of that list into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, filter, import, copy

I'd like to fix the code below so that when the multiple csv's are imported into a master sheet, a filtered version of that data is copied onto a new sheet.

The importing of multiple csv's works fine, but when it comes to copying a filtered version of the list, it just copies the entire file unfiltered.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
Sub CSV_Import()

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim destinationWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("csv-FileToOpen (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=True)
   
    If Not IsArray(FileToOpen) Then Exit Sub
   
    Set destinationWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   
    nextRow = 1
    For i = LBound(FileToOpen) To UBound(FileToOpen)
        Set OpenBook = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen(i), local:=True)
        With OpenBook.ActiveSheet
            Set sourceRange = .UsedRange.Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1)
        End With
        sourceRange.Copy destinationWorksheet.Cells(nextRow, "A")
        nextRow = nextRow + sourceRange.Rows.Count
        
        OpenBook.Close False
    Next i
    
    Sheet3.Cells.Clear
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BU100000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriarange:=Range("BY1:BY2"), copytorange:=Sheet3.Range("A1"), Unique:=False

    Sheet7.Cells.Clear
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BU100000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, criteriarange:=Range("BZ1:BZ2"), copytorange:=Sheet7.Range("A1"), Unique:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
End Sub
```

Comment: `criteriarange:=Range("BY1:BY2")` - Range is unqualified, it does not explicitly define the sheet. Try `criteriarange:=destinationWorksheet.Range("BY1:BY2")`

Comment: Thank you so much CDP1802, your solution works perfectly, that was driving me crazy! Much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you also change `Worksheets("Sheet1")` to `destinationWorksheet` to avoid an unqualified worksheet. Or neater wrap the 2 filter lines in a `With destinationWorksheet .. End With` block.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with the VBA, but you should look into using PowerQuery for this. It is exactly what it is meant for. You can put your CSV files in a folder and then use the 'Get Data>From Folder' option in the Data ribbon of Excel. PowerQuery will combine the files and then give you an option to filter the data and do other transformations before outputting to a table in the workbook.

Comment: Thanks @CPD1802, I've made those amendments. I need to ask another question about another part of the code, is it best to post a new question for that or to just add a comment here? Not sure of the etiquette.